# How to precisely control font-size on html page?

Tags: html, typesetting

For example, when I set `font-size = 25px` with some particular font-family, I want to get a `25px` character on html page. But the rendered character is maybe `27px` or some value else.

How can I precisely control the *exact* rendered font size of text?

Comment: Please try and avoid all the fluff in your questions. It's a lot to read through for a simple question.  What have you tried? What fonts fail?

Comment: @user0141016: I condensed your question a bit, as people generally won't read a wall of text. Undo my edit if you feel that I've changed something substantial in the meaning of your question.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing absolute about font sizes. The pixel size of a typeface is related to the point size, but that relationship can vary, and the point size itself is a relative term, not absolute. The general concept dates back to the days of lead type. You can read more about that here: http://nwalsh.com/comp.fonts/FAQ/cf_8.htm

Point size refers to the height of the font, not the width. It generally refers to the cap-height, but that can vary between fonts, platforms and browsers. And the height can vary between characters in the same font. For example, a capital 'O' will extend slightly below the baseline and above the cap line, while a capital 'H' will be flush with both.

I'm not sure what you're really trying to accomplish, but learning a bit more about typography might give you some good insights.

Comment: Hi ddrace, You answer is really useful to me. I am going to check that link out and give you more replies.